# How to build hierarchy using as few queries as possible (one?)

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I have a newer SQLServer with a database with one table of customers, and one table with relationships (parent/child relationships). The relationships may be of different types (ie, standard company hierarchy, friends, competition etc).

I want to list a complete company hierarchy (specific relationship type) by starting with a single customer. Just a complete list, it does not have to be ordered as that will be taken care of outside.

I am able to do this with my web-script which will build the visual part, but there may be some huge hierarchies there and it will cause hundreds of single queries to run. That may become too time-consuming.

I've tried to look at CTE (common table expression), but I don't think I really understand it. I seem to be able to list all where my starting customer is part of, but not where it is not part at all.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
 id int not null, 
 name varchar(100) not null
);


CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIPS
(
 relationid int not null,
 relationtype int not null,
 customerid int not null,
 parentid int not null
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(id,name) VALUES 
(1040,'Cust A'),
(1041,'Cust B'),
(1042,'Cust C'),
(1043,'Cust D'),
(1044,'Cust E'),
(1045,'Cust F'),
(1046,'Cust G'),
(1047,'Cust H');

INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIPS(relationid,relationtype,customerid,parentid)
VALUES
(1,1,1041,1040),
(2,1,1042,1040),
(3,1,1043,1042),
(4,1,1047,1043),
(5,2,1041,1040);
```

Current SQL

```
with cte as (
    select t.parentid,parent.name as parentname,t.customerid,child.name as childname
    from RELATIONSHIPS t
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS parent ON t.parentid = parent.id
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS child ON t.customerid = child.id
    where relationtype = 1 and (customerid = 1042 or parentid = 1042)

    union all

    select t.parentid,parent.name as parentname,t.customerid,child.name as childname
    from RELATIONSHIPS t
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS parent ON t.parentid = parent.id
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS child ON t.customerid = child.id
    inner join cte c on (c.customerid=t.parentid )
    where relationtype = 1
)
select distinct t.* from cte t;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e919b/14

Based on the data in the data above, i want this listed:

```
1040,Cust A,1041,Cust B
1040,Cust A,1042,Cust C
1042,Cust C,1041,Cust D
1043,Cust D,1047,Cust H
```

My query above try to list the entire hierarchy tree where customer 1042 ( Cust C) is part. With my query I seem to get all, except the one for child 1041 (Cust B). Not sure how to include such things in a query, as it isn't directly related to my starting company (except being in same hierarchy).

Comment: Looking at your data cust B isn't isn't the same branch as Cust C, so why are expecting it for those related to C? It's related to A, and only A.

Comment: Cust B and Cust C is related in the sense that they share parent (cust A). I want to list all in the same hierarchy, no matter if they are related to the the record I start with (this case Cust C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God this is ugly. No idea if this is the best performer or not. What you're effectively saying is you want all the children of your customer (`'Cust C'`) all the parents of your customer, **and** then all the children of those parents (that weren't in the prior branch(es)). I've ended up doing this with 3 rCTEs, which is probably an absolute performance killer on a larger data set, but hey, it gets the job "done":

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
 id int not null, 
 name varchar(100) not null
);


CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIPS
(
 relationid int not null,
 relationtype int not null,
 customerid int not null,
 parentid int not null
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(id,name) VALUES 
(1040,'Cust A'),
(1041,'Cust B'),
(1042,'Cust C'),
(1043,'Cust D'),
(1044,'Cust E'),
(1045,'Cust F'),
(1046,'Cust G'),
(1047,'Cust H');

INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIPS(relationid,relationtype,customerid,parentid)
VALUES
(1,1,1041,1040),
(2,1,1042,1040),
(3,1,1043,1042),
(4,1,1047,1043),
(5,2,1041,1040);
GO

DECLARE @Customer varchar(100) = 'Cust C';
--Get the children of the Customer
WITH Children AS(
    SELECT Cp.name AS ParentName,
           Cp.Id AS ParentID,
           CC.name AS ChildName,
           Cc.id AS ChildID
    FROM CUSTOMERS Cp
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON Cp.id = R.parentid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cc ON R.customerid = Cc.id
    WHERE Cp.name = @Customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.ChildName AS ParentName,
           C.ChildID AS ParentID,
           Cc.name AS ChildName,
           Cc.Id AS ChildId
    FROM Children C
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON C.ChildID = r.parentid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cc ON R.customerid = Cc.id),
--Get the Parents of the customer
Parents AS(
    SELECT Cp.name AS ParentName,
           Cp.Id AS ParentID,
           CC.name AS ChildName,
           Cc.id AS ChildID
    FROM CUSTOMERS Cc
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON Cc.id = R.customerid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cp ON R.parentid = Cp.id
    WHERE Cc.name = @Customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Cp.name AS ParentName,
           Cp.Id AS ParentID,
           P.ParentName AS ChildName,
           P.ParentID AS ChildId
    FROM Parents P
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON P.ParentID = R.customerid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cp ON R.parentid = Cp.id),
--Get the children of the parents. Yuck
ParentChildren AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           P.ParentName AS ParentName,
           P.ParentID AS ParentID,
           Cc.name AS ChildName,
           Cc.id AS ChildId
    FROM Parents P
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON P.ParentID = R.parentid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cc ON R.customerid = Cc.id    
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Parents E
                      WHERE E.ChildID = Cc.id
                        AND E.ParentID = P.ParentID)
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT PC.ChildName AS ParentName,
           PC.ChildId AS ParentID,
           Cc.name AS ChildName,
           Cc.id AS ChildID
    FROM ParentChildren PC
         JOIN RELATIONSHIPS R ON PC.ChildId = R.parentid
         JOIN CUSTOMERS Cc ON R.customerid = Cc.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Parents E
                      WHERE E.ChildID = Cc.id
                        AND E.ParentID = PC.ParentID)
)

SELECT *
FROM Children
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Parents
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ParentChildren
ORDER BY ParentID ASC;

GO

DROP TABLE RELATIONSHIPS;
DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: This certainly seems like the correct way of doing this in one go. I will test this on a larger setup this week where I can test performance. Would it maybe be better performance wise to break it into a few more queries, where I could use result from one in the next (id not in list from the first or similar)?

Comment: That is what the final rCTE does use @EirikR . Notice the `EXISTS` in the `WHERE`. Theres no need in the first 2 as they in opposite "directions".

Comment: Quick feedback, while this is working on my small dataset here, it exhaust the max recursions in my live environment. Even with max 30000 or even 0, it's a no go. I do have little control over this environment, and there may be some circular references going on for all I know. Relationships table has only about 20k rows.

Comment: If you have circular references, you need to fix those, @EirikR. This solution works for "good" data, but an answer is only as good as the data. If the data is in a poor state, it's the data that needs fixing. Like any other rCTE, it will "fall over" with circular references.

Comment: You are correct @Larnu. However, I do not think I am able to fix this as this is set on an individual basis in that system, and it doesn't care if the customer you are setting as parent actually is a child as well somewhere down in the hierarchy. Your answer is still correct of course, given the presented data.